# wolf xmr miner v0.4 configuration gpu

Tags: gpu-mining

I want to use this miner but don't want it to control anything about the GPU. This will be controlled by MSI Afterburner which I know works just fine with my cards.

So do I need to give the miner all this information like GPU speed and Fan speed?

Also I never got it to work. Even when downloading sample configs which should work fine it tells me:

```
[15:28:30] Error loading configuration file: '}' expected near end of file on line 24.
```

Everytime this error ...?
This one was printed out with this configuration:

```
{
"Algorithms":
[
    {
        "name": "CryptoNight",
        "devices":
        [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "threads": 1,
                "rawintensity": 1040,
                "worksize": 16
            }
        ],
        "pools":
        [
            {
                "url": "xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14444",
                "user": "-",
                "pass": "x"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Anybody knows whats wr

Answer (score 2):

You need a curly brace at the very end of the program.